# Prove $V_4\cap K$ is a normal group of $A_4$

Tags: group-theory, permutations

Let $A_4, V_4=\{\text{id},(1,2)(3,4),(1,3)(2,4),(1,4)(2,3)\}$ and $K\leq A_4, |K|=6$

I want to prove $V_4\cap K$ is a normal group of $A_4$
$$\forall \tau\in A_4,\, \forall \sigma\in V_4\cap K\hspace{0.5cm} \tau^{-1}\sigma\tau\in V_4\cap K$$

First I proved $V_4$ is a normal subgroup of $A_4$ then
$$\tau^{-1}\sigma\tau\in V_4 $$

Now How can I prove
$$\tau^{-1}\sigma\tau\in K$$

Comment: @QuangHoang All that I know is $K\leq A_4$ and $|K|=6$ ,that's all ..

Comment: Are you sure such a $K$ exists?  Because I'm not.  In which case, of course, the theorem is true by vacuity of condition.

Comment: @RobertShore this is a first step to prove  $K$ does not exist

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Are you sure such a $K$ exists?  I'm not.  In which case, of course, the theorem is true by vacuity of condition.  But if $K$ does exist, then since $\vert A_4 \vert = 12, [A_4:K]=2$ and $K \lhd A_4$.  Since also $V_4 \lhd A_4$, we have that $K \cap V_4$ is the intersection of two normal subgroups, so it's also normal.

Comment: This is a fist step to prove $K$ does not exist by contradiction

Comment: @JhonKnows As noted in the answer, if $K$ exists, it must be the case that $K \lhd A_4$.

Comment: Thank you so much