# Find $|V_4\cap K|$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, permutations

Let $A_4, V_4=\{\text{id},(1,2)(3,4),(1,3)(2,4),(1,4)(2,3)\}$ and $K\leq A_4, |K|=6$

I want to prove $K$ does not exist by contradiction.

First [I proved $V_4\cap K\trianglelefteq A_4$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4290519/104041) and now  $|V_4\cap K|$ must be $1$ or $2$ by Lagrange's Theorem but I don't know where  the contradiction is.

Any hint please?

Comment: Well, if $|K\cap V_4|=1$, then how many elements does $KV_4$ have?

Comment: And if $|K\cap V_4|=2$, grab an element of order $3$ and use the fact that $K$ must be normal in $A_4$, if it exists.

Comment: @ArturoMagidin If $|K\cap V_4|=1$ then $|KV_4|\geq |K||V_4|=24 $ contradiction because $KV_4\leq A_4$ and $|A_4|$=12, is that correct?

Comment: @ArturoMagidin I'm stuck in the case  $|K\cap V_4|=2$  some help please

Comment: There are not many elements of order $3$ in $A_4$. They all have a particular form. And you can check what they do to the elements of $V$ under conjugation.

Comment: @ArturoMagidin Thank you sooo much , I got it !